# Compare and Copy from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

There are two Excel workbooks, Master and Survey Responses.

I have to loop through each row in Survey Responses, to select the value from the 4th column and compare it to the 4th column in Master. If there is no match then copy the complete row from Survey Responses to the end of Master. For the first time there will be no rows in Master so all rows must be copied from  Survey Responses.

Survey Responses
[image: Survey Responses Excel]

The below code does not loop through all rows and if I run it a second time it copies all rows without performing the comparison.

```
'''''Define Object for Target Workbook
Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Path As String


'''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
Source_Path = "C:\Users\Survey Responses\Survey Response.xls"

Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)
Set Target_Workbook = ThisWorkbook


'''''With Source_Workbook object now, it is possible to pull any data from it
'''''Read Data from Source File


'''''Logic to select unique rows only
Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range, cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range

Set rngSource = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("Responses")
Set rngTarget = Target_Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("Responses")

Dim rowNr_target As Integer, Rng As Range


With Target_Workbook.Sheets(2)
  rowNr_target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim counter As Integer, found As Boolean, inner_counter As Integer
counter = 1

For Each cellSource In rngSource.Rows
 'On Error Resume Next

    If cellSource.Cells(counter, 1).Value = "" Then
      Exit For
    End If

    found = False

    inner_counter = 1

    For Each cellTarget In rngTarget.Rows

        If cellTarget.Cells(inner_counter, 1).Value = "" Then
          Exit For
        End If

        ''''test = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(test1, rngTarget, 1, False)
        If (cellSource.Cells(counter, 4) = cellTarget.Cells(inner_counter, 4)) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If

        inner_counter = inner_counter + 1

    Next

    If (found = False) Then
        cellSource.EntireRow.Copy

        If (rowNr_target > 1) Then
            rngTarget.Rows(rowNr_target + 1).Insert
        Else
            rngTarget.Rows(rowNr_target).Insert
        End If

        rowNr_target = rowNr_target + 1
    End If

    counter = counter + 1
 'On Error GoTo 0

Next

'''''Target_Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("Responses").Value = Source_data


'''''Close Target Workbook
Source_Workbook.Save
Target_Workbook.Save
''''Source_Workbook.Close False

'''''Process Completed
MsgBox "Task Completed"
```

---

Updated code:

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
Dim Source_Path As String


'''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
Source_Path = "C:\Users\Survey Responses\Survey Response.xls"
Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Source_Path)
Set Target_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range, cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range

Set rngSource = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("Responses")
Set rngTarget = Target_Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("Responses")


    With Target_Workbook.Sheets(2)
     lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cel In Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("D:D")

            If cel.Value = "" Then
              Exit For
            End If

            Set r = .Range("D:D").Find(What:=cel, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If r Is Nothing Then
                cel.EntireRow.Copy
                rngTarget.Rows(lastrow).Insert
                ''If Not rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Union(rng, cel) Else Set rng = cel
            End If

        Next cel

        ''rng.Copy.Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End With

'''''Close Target Workbook
Source_Workbook.Save
Target_Workbook.Save
''''Source_Workbook.Close False

'''''Process Completed
MsgBox "Task Completed"
```

Comment: Do you have any code we can take a look at?

Comment: You are struggling so we should write the code for you or you are struggling and are stuck with a specific line of code error and want us to debug?  The first is going to get your question closed, the later requires you to post code.

Comment: I have added the code which I have been able to write so far. Also attached is the image of the survey responses excel.

Comment: @Chrismas007: Can you help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code but it should help you with anything you already have. You will need to adjust the ranges to suit yourself, but it will loop through one sheet and collect values that dont exists and then copy them to another sheet.

Try this,

```
Sub dave()
Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim lastrow As Long


    With Sheets("Master")
     lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D22")
            Set r = .Range("D:D").Find(What:=cel, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If r Is Nothing Then
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Union(rng, cel) Else Set rng = cel
            End If
        Next cel
        rng.Copy
        .Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the code above, can you please look into that and let me know what is the issue.

Comment: I am getting an error Object Required 424 on the last line rng.Copy.Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: I was able work with the code you shared. Many thanks. The only problem is that the rows are copied in reverse order in Master excel. the row at position 1 is being copied at the last and the row at last in the Survey excel is being copied as first row in Master. Can you tell what's happening. I have added my updated code above.

Comment: Please mark the answer solved by clicking the 'Tick' below the arrows. And if that is the case just loop through it backwards as the rows are added in order of the loop.

Comment: I did that and the only problem left is that the rows in the master excel are written from the second row. The code leaves the first row as blank.

Comment: @Do you need the code to copy side by side cells? (not one cell but two)